# how can i sort map data in descending order which is already in ascending order in react-native?

Tags: reactjs, sorting, react-native, mapping

```
constructor(props) {
super(props);
 let comments = [{body: "good", created_at:"2018-02-12T05:27:47.175Z"},
                 {body: "bad article", created_at:"2017-11-12T05:27:47.175Z"}, 
                 {body: "great", created_at:"2017-10-12T05:27:47.175Z"}];
  this.state = { comments };
render() {
 return(
 { comments.map((comment, index) =>
    <Text>{comment.body}</Text>
  )}
 );
};
```

The data comes in descending order but, I want to sort it in ascending order based on `created_at` date.

Now, comment which is new is coming first and I want comment which is old should come first.

How can I sort this comments? Please suggest any solution.

Answer (score 9):

Add a [`.reverse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse).

```
comments.reverse().map((comment) =>
  <Text>{comment.body}</Text>
);
```

Comment: Thank you so much its working

Comment: Hi kalyani, it works for me too, you should mark the answer